# Ltac position argument for instantiate

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

The tactic [`instantiate`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.instantiate) can take  and `ident` or a `num` as:

```
instantiate (ident:= term)

instantiate (num := term)
```

Now I want to use the second one inside a tactic definition. For example:

```
  Ltac my_instantiate n x:=
    instantiate(n:=x).
```

Unfortunately, this gives the following error:

> Ltac variable n is bound to 1 which cannot be coerced to a fresh
>   identifier.

I suspect that ltac is trying to use the first use of `instantiate`. How do I tell coq to instantiate by position, or how do I pass the argumetn correctly?

---

Here is a minimal example:

```
Ltac my_instantiate n x:=
  instantiate(n:=x).
Goal exists x, x = 2.
  eexists.
  my_instantiate 1 2.
  (* Fails with: Ltac variable n is bound to 1 which 
     cannot be coerced to a fresh identifier. *)
```

---

Note: I know that instantiating by position is discouraged, but I'm only using my tactic for exploration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you are looking for can be expressed in terms of a Tactic Notation?

[reference manual - tactic notations](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/user-extensions/syntax-extensions.html#tactic-notations)

Comment: Best I can come up with is `Tactic Notation "my_instantiate" integer(n) ident(x):= instantiate(n:=x).` which still doesn't work. Would you mind sharing what you have in mind?

Comment: This seems like a bug in Coq, and worth reporting as such

Comment: @user2506946 i had something like that in mind. Why it doesn't work is unclear to me.